# Image overlapping of image view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have two  circular images I want to overlap these two images but second image overlap first image by percentage! Gray image and blue image are two separate images. I want to result as shown in attached image.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried so far?

Comment: use a LayerDrawable with one layer as a ClipDrawable

Comment: yet i am not getting idea how to start .please provide example it is really apreciated.

Comment: start as always with reading the javadocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented same thing in our project. Please go through the following snippet :

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagegreenid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/clip_full_green_gauge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagewhiteid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/clip_feil_empty_gauge" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Code in Activity:

```
int total_percent = orininalScore * 100;
int TOTAL_VALUE = 10000;

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagegreenid);
ClipDrawable mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable.setLevel(total_percent);
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagewhiteid);
ClipDrawable mImageDrawable1 = (ClipDrawable) img1.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable1.setLevel(TOTAL_VALUE - total_percent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but for history:) , I guess you can use foreground and background properties. be sure they are both png.

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_event_available_black_48dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/baseline_close_black_36"
            android:foregroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        ></ImageView>
```

[image]